# Consider the equation $x^4-5x^3+2x^2-5x+1=0$

Tags: real-analysis

a.) Solve the equation in complex numbers.

b.) If $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ are the roots of the equation then find $x_{1}^4+x_2^4+x_3^4+x_4^4$

Okay part a was fairly easy as i factored the equation into
$(x^2+1)(x^2-5x+1)$ and solved each for $x$ getting x=Positive or negative $i$

Or $x= \frac{5+\sqrt{21}}{2}$ or $x= (5-\sqrt{21})/2$

The second part is what I am confused on. Do I just square the roots I found and add them up? Or is it asking something completely different?

Comment: One choice is to use $x^4=(x^2)^2=(-1)^2=\dots$ for two of the roots and $x^4=(x^2)^2=(5x-1)^2=25x^2+\dots=\dots$ for two of the roots, but I don't know if that's any simpler than simply squaring twice.

Comment: Not square, but take the fourth power of all the roots and add them.  (It's very likely that this is leading into a discussion of symmetric powers of roots.)

Comment: It is not «positive or negative $i$»: that simply makes no sense. What you mean is $i$ or $-i$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $(x^2+1)(x^2-5x+1)=0$, we have
$$x_1^2=x_2^2=-1$$$$x_i^2=5x_i-1\Rightarrow x_i^4=25x_i^2-10x_i+1=25(5x_i-1)-10x_i+1=115x_i-24$$
for $i=3,4.$

So, we have
$$\begin{align}x_1^4+x_2^4+x_3^4+x_4^4&=(-1)^2+(-1)^2+(115x_3-24)+(115x_4-24)\\&=2+115(x_3+x_4)-48\\&=2+115\times 5-48\\&=529.\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

The second part is asking you to compute the value of $x_1^4+x_2^4+x_3^4+x_4^4$ where $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ are the roots of the polynomial that you found in part (a).

The most straightforward method is to set $x_1 = i$, $x_2 = -i$, $x_3 = \frac{5+\sqrt{21}}{2}$, $x_4 = \frac{5-\sqrt{21}}{2}$.

Then evaluate $x_1^4+x_2^4+x_3^4+x_4^4 = (i)^4+(-i)^4+\left(\frac{5+\sqrt{21}}{2}\right)^4+\left(\frac{5-\sqrt{21}}{2}\right)^4$.

Simplifying $i^4$ and $(-i)^4$ is easy. To simplify $\left(\frac{5+\sqrt{21}}{2}\right)^4+\left(\frac{5-\sqrt{21}}{2}\right)^4$, you will need the Binomial Theorem, specifically, $(a \pm b)^4 = a^4 \pm 4a^3b + 6a^2b^2 \pm 4ab^3 + b^4$

Another method is to use [Newton's Sums](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Newton's_Sums).

Comment: Or just square twice..

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at a slightly different problem: we have $x^2+rx+s=0$ and know that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the roots. Then we can use
$$
(a+b)^4=a^4+4a^3b+6a^2b^2+4ab^3+b^4
$$
to get
\begin{align}
a^4+b^4&=(a+b)^4-4ab(a^2+b^2)-6(ab)^2\\
&=(a+b)^4-4ab((a+b)^2-2ab)-6(ab)^2 &\text{because }a^2+b^2=(a+b)^2-2ab\\
&=(a+b)^4-4ab(a+b)^2+2(ab)^2
\end{align}
Now we know that $x_1+x_2=-r$ and $x_1x_2=s$ (Viète's formulas) so
$$
x_1^4+x_2^4=r^4-4r^2s+2s^2
$$

Now we turn to your equation: we can set $x_1=i$, $x_2=-i$ and get
$$
x_1^4+x_2^4=2
$$
because $r=0$ and $s=1$ (which is also easy to compute directly), while for $x_3=\frac{5+\sqrt{21}}{2}$ and $x_4=\frac{5-\sqrt{21}}{2}$ we have $r=-5$ and $s=1$, so
$$
x_3^4+x_4^4=(-5)^4-4(-5)^2\cdot1+2\cdot1^2=625-100+2=527.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $x_1$ and $x_2$ are $i$ and $-i$, we have $x_1^4+x_2^4=1+1=2$.  The hard part is computing $x_3^4+x_4^4$ for the roots $x_3$ and $x_4$ of $x^2-5x+1=0$.  But we know that $x_3+x_4=5$ and $x_3x_4=1$, hence

$$x_3^2+x_4^2=(x_3+x_x)^2-2x_3x_4=25-2=23$$

and then

$$x_3^4+x_4^4=(x_3^2+x_4^2)^2-2(x_3x_4)^2=23^2-2=527$$

The total is therefore

$$x_1^4+x_2^4+x_3^4+x_4^4=2+527=529$$